# Cloud IAP: how to obtain user profile

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How to obtain the user profile once logged using Cloud IAP?

After logging in, my App Engine Flexible app is correctly receiving the following headers:

- `X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Id`
- `X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email`
- `X-Goog-Iap-Jwt-Assertion`

This way, I can obtain the user id and email.

However, I'd also like to access the user profile picture, etc.

I am trying to GET `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{user_id}`, using the `X-Goog-Iap-Jwt-Assertion` token, to no avail...

What is the correct flow?

Comment: Which error are you getting? It might be that, when requesting the OAUTH token through IAP, you are not asking for the proper scopes that would allow you to get access to the user information.

Comment: On top of what @marcyb5st is requesting, could you add a small code snippet of how are you doing the logging and retrieving the headers?